# Ajax Link in html with jquery

Tags: html, ajax

Anyone know how we create a ajax link when we click any `href` link or input / button, it's work in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler to prevent the browser from trying to browse to the link. Other than that it should be business as usual.

```
$(document).on("click", "a,input,button", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax(...);
});
```